# Regular Expression(Regex) of certain format [party_name] v. [party_name], citation, year

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of content(its a sort of legal document). I have to extract some items from this list which have this expression type mentioned inside parenthesis ([party_name] v. [party_name], citation, year)  You can see it here. [content and expression type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T66F6.jpg)
For convenience, i am showing the list here as well:

```
list1= ['TABLE OF AUTHORITIES',
 'Cases',
 'Agostino v. Quest Diognostics Inc., 256 F.R.D. 437 (D.N.J. 2009)',
 'Amchem Products, Inc. v. Windsor, 521 U.S. 591 (1997)',
 'Arthur Jaffe Associates v. Bilsco Auto Service, Inc., 453 N.Y.S. 2d 501 (App. Div. 1982)',
 'Avritt v. Reliastar Life Ins. Co., 615 F.2d 1023 (8th Cir. 2010)',
 'Beck v. Maximus, Inc., 457 F.3d 291 (3d Cir. 2006)',
 'Carroll v. Cellco Partnership, 713 A.2d 509 (N.J. Super. Ct. App. Div. 1998)',
 'Cox v. Sears Roebuck & Co., 647 A.2d 454 (N.J. 1994)',
 "Cuming v. S.C. Lottery Comm'n, Civil Action No. 05-3608, 2008 WL 906705 (D.S.C. Mar. 28, 2008)",
 'Demmick v. Cellco Parterhship, Civil Action No. 06-2163, 2010 WL 3636216 (D.N.J. Sept. 8, 2010)',
 'Denney v. Deutsche Bank AG, 443 F.3d 253 (2d Cir. 2006)',
 "Elias v. Ungar's Food Products, Inc., 252 F.R.D. 233 (D.N.J. 2008)",
 '*vi Erit v. Judge, Inc., 961 F.Supp. 774 (D.N.J. 1997)',
 'Fink v. Ricoh Corp., 839 A.2d 942 (N.J. Super. Ct. Law Div. 2003)',
 'Folbaum v. Rexall Sundown Inc., Appeal No. A-244-02TI, 2004 WL 3574116 (N.J. Super. Ct. App. Div. 
  May 4, 2004)'
 'Weiss v. York Hosp., 745 F.2d 786 (3d Cir. 1984)',
 'Statutes',
 '28 U.S.C. § 1292(e)',
 '28 U.S.C. § 1332(d)',
 'N.J.S.A. 56:8-2',
 'N.J.S.A. 56:8-19',
 'Rules',]
```

so i want to make a list which contains only the expression types mentioned above. e.g. starting element to be extracted from above mentioned list should be 'Agostino v. Quest Diognostics Inc., 256 F.R.D. 437 (D.N.J. 2009)'
i want to do this using regex expression but if there are other ways that would help as well. this is just a part of content i have shown here. It may be the case that other methods might not work for complete document check so i am asking for regex.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ubershmekel somebody asked me to parse some legal documents and there is a small task to separate out authorities in this document and an authority is identified by this expression type in project and i could not think of any way to come up with some regular expression of such type so posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, you didn't exactly specify which parts to extract. But this is what I got:

```
list1= ['TABLE OF AUTHORITIES',
 'Cases',
 'Agostino v. Quest Diognostics Inc., 256 F.R.D. 437 (D.N.J. 2009)',
 'Amchem Products, Inc. v. Windsor, 521 U.S. 591 (1997)',
 'Arthur Jaffe Associates v. Bilsco Auto Service, Inc., 453 N.Y.S. 2d 501 (App. Div. 1982)',
 'Avritt v. Reliastar Life Ins. Co., 615 F.2d 1023 (8th Cir. 2010)',
 'Beck v. Maximus, Inc., 457 F.3d 291 (3d Cir. 2006)',
 'Carroll v. Cellco Partnership, 713 A.2d 509 (N.J. Super. Ct. App. Div. 1998)',
 'Cox v. Sears Roebuck & Co., 647 A.2d 454 (N.J. 1994)',
 "Cuming v. S.C. Lottery Comm'n, Civil Action No. 05-3608, 2008 WL 906705 (D.S.C. Mar. 28, 2008)",
 'Demmick v. Cellco Parterhship, Civil Action No. 06-2163, 2010 WL 3636216 (D.N.J. Sept. 8, 2010)',
 'Denney v. Deutsche Bank AG, 443 F.3d 253 (2d Cir. 2006)',
 "Elias v. Ungar's Food Products, Inc., 252 F.R.D. 233 (D.N.J. 2008)",
 '*vi Erit v. Judge, Inc., 961 F.Supp. 774 (D.N.J. 1997)',
 'Fink v. Ricoh Corp., 839 A.2d 942 (N.J. Super. Ct. Law Div. 2003)',
 'Folbaum v. Rexall Sundown Inc., Appeal No. A-244-02TI, 2004 WL 3574116 (N.J. Super. Ct. App. Div.  May 4, 2004)',
 'Weiss v. York Hosp., 745 F.2d 786 (3d Cir. 1984)',
 'Statutes',
 '28 U.S.C. § 1292(e)',
 '28 U.S.C. § 1332(d)',
 'N.J.S.A. 56:8-2',
 'N.J.S.A. 56:8-19',
 'Rules',]

import re

new_list = []
for line in list1:
  matches = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z \.]+) v. ([a-zA-Z \.]+),(.*)', line)
  if matches:
    new_list.append(line)

for line in new_list:
  print(line)
```

And that prints out three parts, (partyA, partyB, citation).

```
Agostino v. Quest Diognostics Inc., 256 F.R.D. 437 (D.N.J. 2009)
Amchem Products, Inc. v. Windsor, 521 U.S. 591 (1997)
Arthur Jaffe Associates v. Bilsco Auto Service, Inc., 453 N.Y.S. 2d 501 (App. Div. 1982)
Avritt v. Reliastar Life Ins. Co., 615 F.2d 1023 (8th Cir. 2010)
Beck v. Maximus, Inc., 457 F.3d 291 (3d Cir. 2006)
Carroll v. Cellco Partnership, 713 A.2d 509 (N.J. Super. Ct. App. Div. 1998)
Demmick v. Cellco Parterhship, Civil Action No. 06-2163, 2010 WL 3636216 (D.N.J. Sept. 8, 2010)
Denney v. Deutsche Bank AG, 443 F.3d 253 (2d Cir. 2006)
*vi Erit v. Judge, Inc., 961 F.Supp. 774 (D.N.J. 1997)
Fink v. Ricoh Corp., 839 A.2d 942 (N.J. Super. Ct. Law Div. 2003)
Folbaum v. Rexall Sundown Inc., Appeal No. A-244-02TI, 2004 WL 3574116 (N.J. Super. Ct. App. Div.  May 4, 2004)
Weiss v. York Hosp., 745 F.2d 786 (3d Cir. 1984)
```

Comment: Yours('Agostino', 'Quest Diognostics Inc.', ' 256 F.R.D. 437 (D.N.J. 2009)')  is somewhat similar to required 'Agostino v. Quest Diognostics Inc., 256 F.R.D. 437 (D.N.J. 2009)' but i require what i mentioned latter. I am not sure if regex can really do this, can you guide on this as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer, @MohammadAhmed let me know if that matches what you meant.

Comment: @ubershmekal brother, this is very close effort but it is still missing some entries like  "Elias v. Ungar's Food Products, Inc., 252 F.R.D. 233 (D.N.J. 2008)" maybe due to apostrophie

Comment: @ubershmekal also this is present it contains dash(-) and comma(,) in 'Thiedmann v. Mercedes-Benz USA, LLC, 872 A.2d 783 (N.J. 2005)' how to include this one it. Please inform. I have included apostrophie and its good now. Covering this will complete this, i guess. thanks for your previous

Comment: You're welcome. You can pretty much include any characters you need between those square brackets `[]` though you might need to use `\\` to escape.